# puppet variables overriding fails

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am a newbie on puppet and met some issues as subject, googled for some time but failed with an matched answer. Mys issues is as:

I defined global variables $puppetserver in /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp as below:

```
case $domain {
/domain2/:{
$puppetserver = "puppetserver2"
include migrate
}
default:{
$puppetserver = "puppetserver3"
}
}
```

in node definition of the servers in domain2 in manifests/labs/domain2/nodes.pp

```
   node 'server1.domain2.com' {
    $puppetserver = "puppetserver3"
    }
```

the migrate module is used for puppet migration, got from internet as below:

in /etc/puppet/modules/migrate/manifests/config.pp

```
   class migrate::config  {
  if $puppetserver == undef {
    fail('You must define the targeted Puppet master to perform the migration')
  } 

  augeas { 'puppet.conf.migrate':
    context => '/files/etc/puppet/puppet.conf/main',
    changes => [
       "set server $puppetserver",
    ]
    }

    }
```

Since the node 'server1.domain2.com' can match the domain2 setting in site.pp, so it applies the migrate module,what I expected is: it should get the 'puppetserver3' for $puppetserver defined in node block and then be updated in '/etc/puppet/puppet.conf' by the Augeas, but actual result is : it use 'puppetserver2' which was defined in site.pp. I cannot figure out why overriding is not working. Can you kindly help to check what's wrong?

And as a test:

When I tried to move the 'include migrate' module from site.pp to node 'server1.domain2.com' {} block of nodes.pp, it can work as expected.
it seems some order when puppet applying manifests, but what I got is that local scope variables will always overrides the variables, is that correct?
Thanks a lot for your kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

When you `include` a class at top scope as you do, no node block is in scope during its evaluation.  That's a good reason to avoid such shenanigans.

Put the `include` statement inside the node block, use an ENC to designate the class for inclusion, or maybe use `hiera_include()` inside your node block to include it indirectly.  Alternatively, use hiera at top scope to set the correct value for the `$puppetserver` variable, and thereby take variable shadowing out of the picture.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your suggestion. I will check your suggestion of ENC . the reason I did not put 'include migration' inside the node block is: I would like all other servers to get the puppetserver2 defined in top scope, except the  'server1.domain2.com', so by putting 'include migrate' in top scope , I don't need to put it in every other server's node block  one by sone

Comment: @KevinZH, I urge you to avoid valuing convenience over sound design.  It is rarely a good idea to declare classes at top scope if you are also using node blocks or an ENC.  In any event, I think your best option is to rely on Hiera to set the correct value of your variable -- wherever it is that you need that value -- instead of setting it in one place and overriding it some place else.  The other options will work, but this sort of thing is Hiera's bread & butter.

Comment: Yeah I can't really tell what the root cause is here, but the suggestion for a well-designed node classifier and how to do it (plus use of data) would probably fix it.

Comment: Thank you Jon and Matt for your suggestions. I will avoid declase classes at top scope and start to  check the Hiera methods